# JS dynamically created SVG not working/animating in IOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, polygon

I have this code working perfectly on windows and android in chrome, edge and FF but broken results on ipad in FF, edge, chrome and safari. Basically no animation or sign of this instance on IOS.

```js
var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

//DYNAMICALLY CREATE SVG POLYGON

const bgSvg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
const bgPoly = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'polygon');
const animate = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animate');

bgSvg.setAttribute('class', 'mobiNav_Poly_Close');
bgSvg.setAttribute('width', `${width}`);
bgSvg.setAttribute('height', `${height}`);
bgSvg.setAttribute('fill', 'white');
bgSvg.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);
bgPoly.setAttribute('class', 'Poly_Close');
bgPoly.setAttribute('points', `0,${height} ${width},${height} 0,0 ${width},0`);
animate.setAttribute('attributeName', 'points');
animate.setAttribute('dur', '1s');
animate.setAttribute('keyTimes', '0 ; 1');
animate.setAttribute('keySplines', '.67,.01,.16,1');
animate.setAttribute('calcMode', 'spline');
animate.setAttribute('fill', 'freeze');
animate.setAttribute('from', `${width},${height}, 0,${height}, 0,0 ${width},0`);
animate.setAttribute('to', `${width},${height}, ${width},0, 0,0 ${width},0`);

bgSvg.appendChild(bgPoly);
bgPoly.appendChild(animate);
document.querySelector('.mobiNav_overlay').appendChild(bgSvg);
```

```css
body {
 background-color: black;
}

.mobiNav_overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobiNav_overlay"></div>
```

In another function I have a close state on a click event where this svg element is removed and replaced by essentially the same thing with new points and to/from in reverse. I get what appears to be a flash of garbage (mixed up/transposed points) and no animation. I only have an iPad to test on and so debugging has been tricky to say the least. I've outputted to innerHTML these attributes and all appears normal.

Comment: Might be the same issue that exists with window object in mobile devices. Please provide a jsfiddle or codesandbox to further investigate.

Comment: Can you post the CSS for Poly_Close? The rest looks valid

Comment: @Michael Mullany - Hi, I have no css on anything but the SVG element (mobiNav_Poly_Close) .mobiNav_Poly_Close {
  top: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
 }

Comment: @MannyAlvarado - Hi Manny, jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qpt0e5xu/6/       I'm battling to get the animation in MobiMenuOpen to work in the fiddle. Close works fine.

Comment: You can report webkit bugs [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/)

Comment: I gave up and ended up having to do this with clip-path.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `this` in the html onclick. `this` javascript keyword will return the targeted element so no need to declare it in function params.

```
<div id="menuImg" onclick="MobiMenuOpen();">open</div>
<div id="menuCloseImg" onclick="MobiMenuClose();">close</div>
```

And for both elements try

```
var elem = document.getElementById(this.id);
```